# Vectors, iterators and std::find

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

Is there any way to use different types of iterators in different vectors? Or, is there a function that returns the position of element in vector as an integer?

```
std::vector<DWORD>::iterator it;        // Iterator

// monsterQueue is a <DWORD> vector

it = std::find(bot.monsterQueue.begin(), bot.monsterQueue.end(), object);   
// Check do we have the object in the queue

if(it != bot.monsterQueue.end())    // If we do have it
{
    bot.monsterDists.at(it) = mobDist; // monsterDists is <int> vector
    bot.monsterCoordX.at(it) = PosX; // monsterCoordX is <int> vector
    bot.monsterCoordY.at(it) = PosY; // monsterCoordY is <int> vector too
}
```

That's some sample code, does anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
std::vector<DWORD>::iterator it;        // Iterator

// monsterQueue is a <DWORD> vector

it = std::find(bot.monsterQueue.begin(), bot.monsterQueue.end(), object);   
// Check do we have the object in the queue

if(it != bot.monsterQueue.end())    // If we do have it
{
```

**size_t idx = it - bot.monsterQueue.begin()**

```
    bot.monsterDists.at(idx) = mobDist; // monsterDists is <int> vector
    bot.monsterCoordX.at(idx) = PosX; // monsterCoordX is <int> vector
    bot.monsterCoordY.at(idx) = PosY; // monsterCoordY is <int> vector too
}
```

Also probably it will be a better idea to create a struct with 4 members 'monster',monsterDist and coordinateX and coordinateY and store the struct objects in vector.

Answer (score 12):

```
index = std::distance( monsterQueue.begin(), it );
```

Comment: better to use the difference_type than int for the distance

Answer (score 6):

Simply calculate

```
it - bot.monsterQueue.begin()
```

to get the index.

Comment: +1.  Can I suggest you also mention that this works because a vector is a RandomAccessContainer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the random access in std::vectors:

```
DWORD find_this = 0x0;
int pos = 0;
for (; i<monsterQueue.size(); ++i)
{
    if (monsterQueue[i]==find_this)
        break;
}
```

After the loop, pos will be where the loop broke, i.e. where `find_this` is located. Except, of course, if `find_this` is not even in the vector.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about changing the underlying type of monsterQueue to an object that contains or has references/pointers to monsterDists et al